# Attaching the source of a Gradle plugin in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I have a plugin defined in my `build.gradle` like this:

```
plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.intellij" version "0.2.9"
}
```

And I want to be able to resolve the *sources* for the **plugin**.

Obviously it would be nice if it could happen automatically, but attaching the sources manually is fine at this point. The problem is that there is no reference to the JAR for this plugin anywhere in any setting I could find.

Comment: Check [this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-171875#comment=27-2121934).

Comment: That's definitely the same question, but the solution doesn't seem to help at least for the "org.jetbrains.intellij" plugin.